# How to set time filter for plotted dataframe - Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, legend

I plot a dataframe using `Matplotlib 3.3.0`.

The data-frame's `index` is a `datetime` object with this format:

`2018-05-29 08:09:00` (i.e `year-month-day hour:minute:second`)

How to zoom to an **Hourly** or **Daily** or **Weekly** or **Monthly** time slice? I want to have a few `QPushButton` to enables the user to **zoom** or **pan** to a time slice with the length of a day or week or a month or an hour as shown in the picture.

[image: time-filter buttons]

I plot the data-frame as following:

```
self.canvas.axes.plot(self.df.index, self.df.loc[:, self.comboBox.currentText()], linestyle="None", marker='.')
self.label = self.canvas.axes.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=9)
self.label = self.canvas.axes.set_ylabel('Temperature - k [°C]', fontsize=9)
self.canvas.axes.legend('Temperature - k [°C]', bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc='upper center', ncol=8, mode=None, borderaxespad=0.)
```

The second problem is that the **legend** isn't shown completely. Only its first character is displayed. How to fix it?

---

**Updated:**
I tried plotting the data-frame based on a time element as X-axis like:

```
self.canvas.axes.plot(self.new_df.index.hour, self.new_df.loc[:, self.comboBox.currentText()])
```

But, since the values of `hour`s are repeating over each day and over the whole data-frame, then the plot isn't drawn correctly like below picture:

[image: data drawn incorrectly due to repeated values for X-axis]

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks the legend worked, great. As regards time filters, I tried to pass `df.index.month` or `df.index.hour` as X-axis data to `plot` function, but, since the values of time (such as hours of the day ) are repeated over and over, then the plot isn't drawn correctly.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney: Question is updated. any idea is appreciated.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I took the idea of canvas from [here](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/graphics-plotting/plotting-matplotlib). It simply use matplotlib to plot data in a canvas. the problem is that passing more than one element as a list to X-axis of plot function like: `self.canvas.axes.plot( (self.df.index.hour, self.df.index.minute),  self.df.loc[:, self.comboBox.currentText()])`. it throws back this error: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (2, 7523) and (7523,)`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney link revised [learnpyqt.com - Plotting with Matplotlib](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/graphics-plotting/plotting-matplotlib/)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney: I believe this is a `matplotlib` question and has nothing to do  with PyQt5. the provided link uses some built-in methods from 'sqlite3' library to apply a time interval only to select data froma database which I cannot convert to pandas. BTW, thanks.

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to achieve. You mentioned originally that you want to zoom (which I read as silce/filter date column and possibly resampling). In your update you seem to attempt a resampling but no slicing. Anyways, have you tried `.groupby(df.index.ceil())`? Or `.resample()`? Docs about [ceil](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.ceil.html) and [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the trick:

```
self.canvas.axes.scatter(df_day.index, df_day.loc[:, item], linestyle="None", marker='.')

self.canvas.axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(0.19))
self.canvas.axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%b %H:%M'))
```